# memcpy one buffer to another with 2 different sizes

Tags: c++

Trying to copy one buffer to another and i allocate the space for it but crashes when i go to delete the pointer.

```
size_t marble_length = marble->get_length();
unsigned char* marble_buffer = marble->get_buffer();

// create a new marble buffer
size_t marble_size = marble_length + 3;
unsigned char* send_buffer = new unsigned char[marble_size]();

// copy the marble_buffer into the send_buffer
memcpy(send_buffer + 3, marble_buffer, buffer_size);

// call a function to insert 3 data into send_buffer
to_->create_(send_buffer, static_cast<unsigned short>(marble_size));

boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
            boost::asio::buffer(send_buffer, marble_size),
            std::bind(&session::send_handler,
                shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2, send_buffer));


void session::send_handler(const boost::system::error_code& ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred, unsigned char* send_buffer)
{
    if (!ec)
    {
        // free the memory allocated for the send buffer
        delete[] send_buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any reason you're not using a `std::vector` to mange your buffers for you?

Comment: what is `buffer_size` ?

Comment: marble_size is buffer_size sorry labeled it wrong my getbuffer is a std:unique_ptr<unsigned char> buffer and i cant copy a unique_ptr to a std::vector